# Is there anyway to use colour picker in dart as use it fro templates

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to design my own template by clicking on colours which I choose by myself

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there is no direct way, you have to take a large colour array and then apply check on each of them which is very tedious task, better use [this](https://pub.dev/packages/flex_color_picker) dependency, it will solve your problem